# CloudianOS Aml v1.2.7 command line for reboot using quick cache argument

Tags: shell, caching, command-line, terminal, command

I am new to CloudianOS Aml (Have only used the Glass '18 distribution afore) and it seems to be much different than its other distributions.

Here's a line from the changelog on August 25th
[image: Changelog from August 25th]

My application requires a system restart (after the user agrees on a prompt), however, when executing a general reboot (what `power reboot` does) some of my processes are started all over (without their cache and data, which prevents the app from knowing where it ended and where to proceed).

I did some research and it seems like application cache and data (didn't really understand when does it apply for data) is saved in "quick cache storage" (which isn't cleaned after the reboot).

I tried all these:
[image: Attempting to find the correct quick storage restart command]

I also tried executing those with QuickAccess. None worked.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: how are you requesting the reboot? Via a CCD, or via the `os` method? I'm not really an expert, but I think you need a permission to reboot.Please give more info about your app

Comment: @ZefirZdravkov My whole application is based on native CCD code. I have the permission node to reboot (used `perm "os.power.reboot"` and `perm "os.power.reboot.*"`) and I am able to execute a reboot, alas, I am having difficulties finding the appropriate way to pass an argument to the "power" command as to perform reboot with quick cache.

Comment: I understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick storage is defined by two ways: just an uppercase "Q" in `ccd` and and `index.storage.quick` when using `os.exec(params)` and etc

It is tricky to figure but I think the correct command is `power restart -Q`. Use a singular dash to define a param and then the name of the param "Q".

Comment: Failed to build application. Line 374:7 myThemes.ccd
ERROR Power mode "reboot -Q" not found.

I think it has to be `power restart -Q`